# Having trouble assigning different .env files to different environments

Tags: reactjs, environment, dotenv

I inherited a React project which has dotenv installed. There are three files .env, .env.staging and .env.production. It doesn't appear as though the .env.staging file was working properly though. Unclear.

.env file:

```
NODE_ENV=development
HTTPS=false
REACT_APP_DOMAIN=**mylocalapi**
```

.env.staging:

```
NODE_ENV=staging
HTTPS=true
REACT_APP_DOMAIN=https://**stagingwebsite**
```

.env.production:

```
NODE_ENV=production
HTTPS=true
REACT_APP_DOMAIN=https://**productionwebsite**
```

Inside the package.json file is the following:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts  start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build",
    "build:production": "env-cmd -f .env.production npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

I've been going around in circles for hours trying to work out how to tell each environment which .env file to use. A lot of answers say it is the NODE_ENV variable... But this is inside the files?! It's a catch 22.

I've tried physically setting an environment variable named "NODE_ENV" on the server running it, but that doesn't seem to work. Strangly enough, the staging website is picking up the .env.production file (not the other two), so *something* is triggering this. I know its using the .env.production file because it is pointing to the backend app URL that is in that file.

I'm running both the staging and production websites as Azure static web apps.

I saw online some suggestions about creating different build folders, using a variable in the .env files called OUTPUT_DIR. I then tried running "npm run build:staging", but the build still goes to the standard "build" folder.

Should something be tweaked in our .yml files? Here is the .yml file for the staging site:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

env:
  CI: ""

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      - name: Set NODE_ENV
        run: echo "NODE_ENV=staging" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.xxx}}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} # Used for Github integrations (i.e. PR comments)
          action: "upload"
          ###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
          # For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "api" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "build" # Built app content directory - optional
          ###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.xxx}}
          action: "close"
```

Is there something I can pass in to force it to do build:staging?

I feel I am missing something really basic here but I can't see the oversight. Someone please help?

**EDIT:**
I'm not sure if this is the best strategy, but I have two branches on the one repo. One "staging" branch and one "production" branch. I've edited the .env.production file on both and set the relevant API URL in this file. No idea why they both pull from this file and how to change which file they read from, but seems having a different version across the branches works. It just means I can never merge my staging into production..?

I'd prefer to try and still reference the correct file somehow.